# address.transfer(uint amount) TRON blockchain

Tags: solidity, remix

msg.sender.transfer(amount)

// 1) Is it true, that when I execute this code inside the function, it sends the amount to that contract?
// 2) Is there any function, which does the opposite(from contract to msg.sender)? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`msg.sender.transfer(amount)` transfers the given amount from the contract to msg.sender